# Value from view to action method using ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pass value from view to action method using **ActionLink**

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Click here", "GetvaluefromView", "ActionLink2", new { id = 3 })
```

My controller action method looks like below

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetvaluefromView(int  ? Str )
    {
        return View("Methodname");
        //http://localhost:1542/ActionLink2/Methodname
    }
```

But this is not passing the value to action method.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: remove `[HttpPost]` attribute from controller

Comment: Thanks Works Perfect now   AliRıza Adıyahş